# NullPointerException being thrown, but is clearly not null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, nodelist

I have this method that retrieves a [`NodeList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) of all the elements by tag name in a loaded XML document, which is given in the form of a [`InputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html).  Here is what that looks like:

`MainActivity.java`

```
...
ArrayList<NodeList> nLists = new ArrayList<NodeList>();
NodeList nList = Helper.getNodeList(context.getAssets().open("feed.xml"), "item");
nLists.add(nList); // NullPointerException being thrown originates from this line
...
```

---

`Helper.java`

```
...
public static NodeList getNodeList(InputStream file, String nodeName) {
  dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  try {
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    return doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
  } catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
...
```

---

`feed.xml`

```
<data>
  <item>
    ...
  </item>
  <item>
    ...
  </item>
  <item>
    ...
  </item>
</data>
```

---

For some reason, there is a [`NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) being thrown on the line notated above in MainActivity.java, but if I surround that line with a try/catch block and continue the script, everything works fine, and I can use the NodeList without any problems.

So what I'm asking is, why is a [`NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) being thrown when the result is clearly not null?

### EDIT:

Okay, I tried, eliminating the ArrayList altogether, and doing this instead (just for testing):

```
String s = Helper.getNodeList(context.getAssets().open("feed.xml"), "item").item(0).getNodeName();
Log.v("MainActivity", "" + s);
```

And the log output showed the correct node name ("item").  However, a NPE was still thrown on the line where `s` was defined.

Comment: Is your NPE actually being thrown from that line? Or is it being thrown from within the add method (ie `nList` is null, not `nLists`)

Comment: Can you check whether nList==null before you insert it? It appears your getNodeList method can potentially return a null element.

Comment: @codeMagic It is not null, because after adding it to the ArrayList, I can get child nodes and other things like the tag name with no problem

Comment: @Takendarkk - I surrounded it with a try/catch block and ran it with no problem.

Comment: Post the stacktrace so we can be sure you are looking at the correct line

Comment: "I surrounded it with a try/catch block and ran it with no problem." Supressing exceptions doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I could fully use the variable nList with no problem.  For example: nList.item(0).getNodeName() returned "item", which is correct.

Comment: Are you sure you have pin-pointed the right line for the NullPointerException. You should be able to add null elements, so the only cause I can see is that your ArrayList isn't initialized.

Comment: As already requested, we need to see the stack trace to help you.

Comment: My guess is the offending code is really being called more than once. First time nList is set null. Adding try/catch allows this to fail silently. Second call works. To wit an uncaught exception in the helper will cause this.

Comment: Okay, I tried loading another xml file, just for the heck of it, different nodes, different layout and everythng, and no NPE was thrown!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a NullPointerException at

```
nLists.add(nList); // NullPointerException being thrown originates from this line
```

this means that for some reason **nLists** is null, even if nList would have been null, it wouldn't throw an exception there, because the JDK ArrayList implementation allows for null as element of the list
But if that code block is really like that and you are initializing the ArrayList just 2 statements earlier with

```
ArrayList<NodeList> nLists = new ArrayList<NodeList>();
```

you should probably check again if the exception really occurred in that line.

Otherwise there in only the possibility that then initialization already failed, because of for example class not found exceptions or sth. like that.

Comment: My ArrayList is explicitly initialized, unconditionally, just two lines before the NPE.  I updated my question with more info.

Comment: I had a typo in in the arraylist call, and Android Studio wasnt saying anything.